# find product in nested list python of non zeros

Tags: python

How can I get product of nested list :

```
[[-1, 3, 1],[6, 1, 2],[4, 3, 1],[0, 1, 1]]
```

to:

```
[-3,12,12,1]
```

where eg : -1 * 3 * 1 = -3 and so on.

This is my current solution :

```
for i in range(len(array2)):
    for j in range(len(array2[i])):
        prod = array2[i][j] * array2[i][j + 1] * array2[i][j + 2] 
        print(prod)
```

I'm getting the following error :

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: is your nested list always has 3 elements ? I mean in general case is it N by 3 ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Why is the last result `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: forgot to mention that if product return 0, it should ignore 0. and only get product of non zero @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look at [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.mul) combined with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for this to make it short and very clear and totally avoid indexing (which is often the source of small errors):

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

l = [[-1, 3, 1],[6, 1, 2],[4, 3, 1],[0, 1, 1]]

[reduce(mul, s) for s in l]
# [-3, 12, 12, 0]
```

**Edit based on comment**

If you want to ignore zeros, you can simply filter them out (this assumes that you don't have rows of all zeros, in which case it's not clear what the answer would be):

```
[reduce(mul, filter(None, s)) for s in l]
# [-3, 12, 12, 1]
```

Comment: forgot to mention that if product return 0, it should ignore 0. and only get product of non zero

Answer (score 0):

Your index is out of bounds when you get j+1 and j+2, the correct way is to stop at len-2

```
array2 = [[-1, 3, 1], 
           [6, 1, 2],
           [4, 3, 1],
           [0, 1, 1]]


for i in range(len(array2)):
    for j in range(len(array2[i])-2): # Check here the range
        prod = array2[i][j] * array2[i][j + 1] * array2[i][j + 2] 
        print(prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

`input_list = [[-1, 3, 1], [6, 1, 2], [4, 3, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`

`def compute_multiplication(nested_list):
    for l in nested_list:
        res = 1
        for element in l:
            res *= element
        print(res)`

With the final line being:

`compute_multiplication(input_list)`

This provides the following output:

-3

12

12

0

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [[-1,3,1],[6,1,2],[4,3,1],[0,1,1]]
products = []
for sub_list in my_list:
  partial_prod = 1      
  for item in sub_list:
    partial_prod = partial_prod * item
  products.append(partial_prod)
```

Comment: forgot to mention that if product return 0, it should ignore 0. and only get product of non zero

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [numpy.prod()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-prod-python/) :

```py
import numpy

matrix = [
    [-1, 3, 1],
    [6, 1, 2],
    [4, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 1]
]

for row in matrix:
    prod = numpy.prod(row)
    print(prod)
```

Comment: If you are going to use Numpy, don't write a loop(that kind of defeats the purpose), just pass the axis: `numpy.prod(matrix, axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is that there are only three entries per row : a list comprehension should suffice. Multiply each item by the other in each row :

```
matrix = [
    [-1, 3, 1],
    [6, 1, 2],
    [4, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 1]
]
```

first, make a condition to change zero values to 1 (this is based on the condition, that 0 be ignored and only the result of non zeros be returned)

```
filtered = [[ent if ent!= 0 else 1 for ent in row  ] for row in matrix]
```

multiply each entry by the other

```
res = [start*middle*end for start,middle,end in filtered]

#[-3, 12, 12, 1]
```

if the number of entries is more than three, then @mark meyer's solution is apt for this